# Get the table name of each row from inherited tables

Tags: postgresql

Take the following query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE users
(
    user_id SERIAL,
    name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE admins
(
    section integer
) INHERITS(users);

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Kevin');
INSERT INTO admins (name, section) VALUES ('John', 1);

CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.is_admin(INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
DECLARE
    result      boolean;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO result COUNT(*) > 0
    FROM admins
    WHERE user_id = $1;
    RETURN result;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT name, pg_temp.is_admin(user_id) FROM users;
```

Is there any postgres feature that would allow me to get rid of the is_admin function? Basically to check the row class type (in terms of inheritance)?

I understand the table design isn't ideal, this is just to provide a simple example so I can find out if what I am after is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of a row's source table when querying the parent it inherits from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580352/get-the-name-of-a-rows-source-table-when-querying-the-parent-it-inherits-from)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [the `tableoid` hidden column for this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html).

```
SELECT tableoid, * FROM users;
```

or in this case:

```
SELECT tableoid = 'admins'::regclass AS is_admin, * FROM users;
```

Note, however, that this will fall apart horribly if you want to find a *non-leaf* membership, i.e. if there was `superusers` that inherited from `admins`, a superuser would be reported here with `is_admin` false.

AFAIK there's no test for "is member of a relation or any child relation(s)", though if you really had t you could get the oids of all the child relations with a subquery, doing a `tableoid IN (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: I can see where this would fall apart yes. It would seem then that postgres' "inheritance" features are very limited then in comparison to C# for example. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yeah, Pg table inheritance is pretty limited. It's also quirky. In particular you can't have a unique constraint that spans all members of an inheritance tree, or a foreign key that references rows that may appear in any child of a parent table.